# JavaScript post it notes can't create new div box

Tags: javascript

I've been searching a lot on the site and the web but can't really seem to find any help. My problem is that I need to make a function that creates a new div box on the press of a button and that div box needs to be draggable and editable.

```js
function makeNote(e) {

    // Check the event object if the .click is on the canvas
    // or a created note
    if (e.eventPhase === 2) {

        // Create the new comment at the corsor postition
        var $newbox = $('<div class="ui-widget-content" id="newbox" style="top:' + e.pageY + 'px; left: ' + e.pageX + 'px;"><span id="close">Delete comment</span><p>Your comment:</p><textarea></textarea></div>');
        $('#canvas').append($newbox);
        $newbox.draggable();

    }

}


function deleteNote() {
    $(this).parent('#newbox').remove();
}

// wait until the dom document is loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // listen for a .click() event on the canvas element
    $('#canvas').click(function (e) {
        makeNote(e);
    });

    // Remove the note
    $("#close").click(function () {
        deleteNote();
    });

});
```

```css
html, body { 
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#newbox {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
textarea {
    background: transparent;
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 0;
}
#canvas {
    height:auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ahref="StyleSheet1.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="canvas">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what problem did you run into while making it? I inderstand what do you need done, but what question do you have?

Comment: each time i type the code in visual studio nothing works but i wanna make a button which makes the same note as i it does on the click... try run it and look on the error message on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

draggable is a part of jquery-ui library. Not jquery.

Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` to your code.

```js
function makeNote(e) {

    // Check the event object if the .click is on the canvas
    // or a created note
    if (e.eventPhase === 2) {

        // Create the new comment at the corsor postition
        var $newbox = $('<div class="ui-widget-content" id="newbox" style="top:' + e.pageY + 'px; left: ' + e.pageX + 'px;"><span id="close">Delete comment</span><p>Your comment:</p><textarea></textarea></div>');
        $('#canvas').append($newbox);
        $newbox.draggable();

    }

}


function deleteNote() {
    $(this).parent('#newbox').remove();
}

// wait until the dom document is loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // listen for a .click() event on the canvas element
    $('#canvas').click(function (e) {
        makeNote(e);
    });

    // Remove the note
    $("#close").click(function () {
        deleteNote();
    });

});
```

```css
html, body { 
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#newbox {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
textarea {
    background: transparent;
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 0;
}
#canvas {
    height:auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ahref="StyleSheet1.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="canvas">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use jQuery, you can use `.draggable()` from jQuery UI along with `contenteditable="true"`:

```js
function addNew() {
  var field = $('<div contenteditable="true">Text</div>')
  
  field.appendTo('#fields').draggable();
}
```

```css
#fields div {
  border: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<button onClick="addNew()">Add new field</button>
<hr/>
<div id="fields"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something I want to notice.

1. never use same id to elements.
2. use jquery `.on` function for element that make by scripts.
3. never use box-shadow :D

```js
function makeNote(e) {

    // Check the event object if the .click is on the canvas
    // or a created note
    if (e.eventPhase === 2) {

        // Create the new comment at the corsor postition
        var $newbox = $('<div class="ui-widget-content" id="newbox'+e.pageX+e.pageY+'"><span class="close">Delete comment</span><p>Your comment:</p><textarea></textarea></div>');
        
        $('#canvas').append($newbox);
        $($newbox).css({
          'top' : ($('#canvas').height() / 2 - 150 + sequentCounter++) + 'px' ,
          'left' : ($('#canvas').width() / 2 - 100 + rowSeqCounter + sequentCounter++) + 'px' 
        });
        $newbox.draggable({cancel : '.close'});
    }

}
var sequentCounter = 1;
var rowSeqCounter = 1;
// wait until the dom document is loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // listen for a .click() event on the canvas element
    $('#div_element_maker').click(function (e) {
      if (sequentCounter > 70){
        sequentCounter = 1;
        rowSeqCounter += 11;
        if (rowSeqCounter > 50)
          rowSeqCounter = 1;
        }
        makeNote(e);
    });

    // Remove the note
    $('#canvas').on('click',".close", function () {
        $(this).parent().remove()
    });

});
```

```css
html, body { 
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.ui-widget-content {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    height: 180px;
    width: 185px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    /*box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888;*/
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
textarea {
    background: transparent;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
#canvas {
    height:auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: -1000;
}
.close{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
}
#div_element_maker{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ahref="StyleSheet1.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="canvas">
    <span id="div_element_maker">make element</span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thansk mate you did kinda almost exactly what i need but all i need now is to add the box to a button instead of mouseclick

Comment: Try to change the selector `$("#canvas").click(...` to your button `$('#div_maker_button').click(...`